# Host Symfony website on a Synology NAS not working

Tags: symfony, deployment, virtualhost, synology

I'm in trouble with my hosting on my synology NAS... I've set up my web station, gave the permissions on 80 port, set up a virtual host (not sure if I did it well, I've select the "public" folder of my project) and bought a domain name (on ovh, I've set up a DNS on the NAS ip, not the public ip but the regular ip). DNS kinda works because the website shows me a 403 error (same as if I type the ip of the nas and folder name in the search field.

I'm pretty sure to have missed something simple (so simple that I can't find it on google...) but it makes me crazy... If anyone have an idea, I'm in!

Comment: What do you mean by "regular ip"? Could you check access or error logs on your NAS?

Comment: Why dont you start by putting index.html in your public folder first with "hello world" and see if you can access that.

Comment: I mean "regular ip" by not the public one. I don't have errors on the NAS

I'll try to put a simple index in the public folder, thx for suggestion